# Laravel Collective/html Form - 3 column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I am using Laravel Collective/html Form to create my views in Laravel, and I would want a 3 column view, I cant figure out to remove the spaces between one input to the other, I would like to have a space between the inputs 
**This my form code**

```
<div class="container-fluid"><!-- Row 1 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn2">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    {!! Form::label('reg_no', 'Vessel Reg No:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('reg_no', old('reg_no'), ['class' => 'form-control input-normal','placeholder' => 'Vessel RegNo']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn2">
                <div class="form-group required ">
                    {!! Form::label('captain_name', 'Captain Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('captain_name', old('captain_name'), ['class' => 'form-control input-normal','placeholder' => 'Captain Name']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4" id="userFormColumn2">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    {!! Form::label('vessel_name', 'Vessel Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                    {!! Form::text('vessel_name', old('vessel_name'), ['class' => 'form-control input-normal','placeholder' => 'Vessel Name']) !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Image**
See the current view

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0oP0.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In default bootstrap has the following style:

```
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Your *col-lg-4* must have these styles, *padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;* otherwise it will be like what u showed in the attached image.

Note: your other styles written for class (userFormColumn2) may be overwritten the default bootstrap styles